# Почему сравнение arraylist не работает?

Tags: java

У меня есть два листа, я хочу сравнить их с друг-другом, если один объект нет в другом листе, то ввести его.
Но мой код не работает, в чем может быть проблема?

```
public void compare() {
    List<PaymentRBS> testRBS = new ArrayList<>();
    PaymentRBS rbs2 = new PaymentRBS(1998, "996552140898", false);
    PaymentRBS rbs3 = new PaymentRBS(1998, "996552140898", false);
    PaymentRBS rbs4 = new PaymentRBS(1998, "996552140898", false);
    PaymentRBS rbs5 = new PaymentRBS(1997, "996552140897", false);
    testRBS.add(rbs2);
    testRBS.add(rbs3);
    testRBS.add(rbs4);
    testRBS.add(rbs5);

    List<PaymentPartner> testPartner = new ArrayList<>();
    PaymentPartner partner1 = new PaymentPartner(1998, "9965522140898", false);
    PaymentPartner partner2 = new PaymentPartner(1998, "9965522140898", false);
    PaymentPartner partner3 = new PaymentPartner(1998, "9965522140898", false);
    PaymentPartner partner4 = new PaymentPartner(1996, "9965522140896", false);
    testPartner.add(partner1);
    testPartner.add(partner2);
    testPartner.add(partner3);
    testPartner.add(partner4);

    log.info("ТРАНЗАКЦИИ КОТОРЫЕ НЕ СОВПАЛИ:");
    try {
        for (PaymentRBS rbs : testRBS) {
            for (PaymentPartner partner : testPartner) {
                if (partner.getAccount().equals(rbs.getAccount()) && partner.getSum() == rbs.getSum()) {
                    partner.setExist(true);
                    rbs.setExist(true);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError | ConcurrentModificationException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    notMatchedRBS = testRBS.stream().filter(r -> !r.isExist()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    notMatchedPartner = testPartner.stream().filter(p -> !p.isExist()).collect(Collectors.toList());

    notMatchedPartner.forEach(System.out::println);
    notMatchedRBS.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

> в чем может быть проблема?

В невнимательности.

```
"996552140898" != "9965522140898"
                         ^
```

Comment: Спасибо, странно что не заметил